# spring data elasticsearch limit the number of returned records

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
    List<List<Object>> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
    nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices("index-log-*");
    SortBuilder sortBuilder = new FieldSortBuilder("nginx.access.request_time");
    sortBuilder.order(SortOrder.DESC);
    nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery(boolQuery()
            .must(rangeQuery("@timestamp").gte(gteTimestamp).lte(lteTimestamp).format("epoch_millis"))
            .must(termQuery("nginx.access.url", dataProviderName))).withSort(sortBuilder).withPageable(PageRequest.of(0,limits));

    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = nativeSearchQueryBuilder.build();
    try {
        SearchHits searchHits = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, SearchResponse::getHits);

        SearchHit[] searchHitArray = searchHits.getHits();
        for (SearchHit searchHit : searchHitArray) {

            IndexInfo dpApiInfo = JSON.parseObject(searchHit.getSourceAsString(), IndexInfo.class);
            // 
        }

        return result;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("error", ex);
        return null;
    }
```

I can use `PageRequest` to set the limits. But I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

```
{
 "size":5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1615441600000,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term" : { "nginx.access.url" : "/test" }
        } 
      ]
    }
  },
   "sort": [
    { "nginx.access.request_time": "desc" }
  ]
}
```

In the Query DSL, I can use **size** to limit the returned quantity. Is there a similar method in spring data elasticsearch?

Version:
<spring-data-elasticsearch.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-data-elasticsearch.version>
<elasticsearch.version>6.8.10</elasticsearch.version>

Comment: I think you can use ```size()``` with your builder.

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using? The code you have seems to be pretty outdated.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch 3.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: @DeepDalsania no `size()` in NativeSearchQueryBuilder

Answer (score 0):

With version 3.2.4 you must stick to paging. Setting the maximum number of returned documents on the classes implementing the `Query` interface was introduced in version 4.0